# ¿Como obtengo la posicion de un dato en un arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, java-8

tengo un `LinkedHashSet` en donde el usuario almacena los datos y quiero saber la posición de un dato en especifico, por ejemplo, "a". Lo intento a través de un `ArrayList` pero me devuelve -1. Aquí mi código:

```
         Set<Attribute> noDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<>((List<Attribute>) args[1]);
                                                        
         noDuplicates.addAll(attributes);
        


        String zu = "a";
        
        for (Attribute x : noDuplicates) {
        
            if(x.value.toString() == zu ) {
                //si es encontrado, se procede a buscar
        Toast.makeText(AppContext.getContext(), "posicionado en: "+ position(new ArrayList<>(noDuplicates), zu), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(AppContext.getContext(), "el elemento no existe o ha sido cambiado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            
            }




    public int position(ArrayList<Attribute> set, String element) {
    
    ArrayList<Attribute> attr = new ArrayList<>(set);
    
    String zu = "a";
    
    
    pos = attr.indexOf(attr.toString() == zu);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    return pos;
    }
```

Intente todas las formas posibles y siempre me devuelve -1

Esta es la clase que representa los datos

```
public String key;
public Value value;
public Drawable ViewItem;

public Attribute(String key, Value value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}


public Attribute copy() {
    return new Attribute(key, value.copy());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return key.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
    
    if(obj == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Attribute)) {
        return false;
    }

    return (this.key.equals(((Attribute) obj).key));
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: quiza debas devolver la ultima posicion del elemento en el Arraylist`nombreArrayList.lastIndexOf(dato);`

Comment: Si, pero es que la lista es dinámica, el usuario puede modificar el arraylist y añadirle más datos, y si el usuario agrega la letra "a" yo tengo que saber la posición de esa letra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr obtener la posición de un elemento, lo que realizas es correcto, solo que la comparación debes realizarla usando `.equals()`, que es lo correcto para realizar la comparación de cadenas, en lugar del operador `==`.

```
   String zu = "a";
   //pos = attr.indexOf(attr.toString() == zu);
   pos = attr.indexOf(attr.toString().equals(zu));
```